# Spring form not able to bind the values when submitted through jquery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I have a JSP with two forms. form1 is used to search the result. The result returned by form1 is shown in form2. form2 is used to edit the result.
 - fomr1 for searching the number

```
            <form:form name="form1" modelAttribute="form1" method="POST" action="doNumEnquiry.do"  id="form1">
            <form:input path="transactionID" type="text" id="trnxRef"/>
            <input type="submit"name="operation" id="searchBtn" value="search"/>
            <form:form>
```

fomr2 for editing enter code here` the number

```
            <form:form name="form2" modelAttribute="form2" method="POST" id="form2">
            <c:forEach items="${form2.numberList}" var="obj">
            <form:radiobutton path="indexRadio" value="${obj.index}" id="indxRadio"/>
            <c:out value="${obj.customerRef}" />
            <input type="button" id="${obj.index}" name="operation" value="Go"/></span>
            </c:forEach>
            </form:form>
            </body>
```

On click of Go butting a Jquery function is called to submit the form2.

```
            $("input[type=button][value=Go]").click(function() {
            var urlVal="doModifyNumEnq.do";
            $("#form2").attr("action",urlVal+"?operation=Go");
            $("#form2").submit();
            });
```

Both the form are calling NumberController. Form1 is a model attribute to doNumberSearch() method of controller. Following are the controller methods.

```
            @RequestMapping(value="doNumEnquiry.do", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="operation=Search")
            public ModelAndView doNumEnquiryWithSearchCriteria(@ModelAttribute("form1") NumberForm form, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
            numberForm = nhNumberService.getNumEnquiryList(nhForm);
            return new ModelAndView("numberSearch", "form2", numberForm);
            }
```

Form2 is a model attribute to doModifyNumberSearch() method of controller.  When I'm trying to get the indexRadio value from the model attribute form2, it is returned as null. Due ti which my service class is throwing null pointer exception.

```
@RequestMapping(value="doModifyNumEnq.do",
method=RequestMethod.POST,params="operation=Go")
public ModelAndView doModifyNumberRequest(@ModelAttribute("form2") NumberForm form, 
    BindingResult result,HttpServletRequest request){
    if(form.getIndexRadio() !=null){
        indexRad=form.getIndexRadio();
    }
    numberForm = nhNumberService.getNumEnquiryList(indexRad);
    return new ModelAndView("exoectedresult", "form", numberForm);
}
```

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Please fix your formatting and also add the source of `NumberForm` so we can help

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the form elements data (not form itself) that is posted to the server. You can directly retrieve the radio value in your controller method using @RequestParam as below

```
@RequestMapping(value="doModifyNumEnq.do",method=RequestMethod.POST,params="operation=Go") 
public ModelAndView doModifyNumberRequest(
    @RequestParam("indexRadio") String indexRad, 
    BindingResult result,
    HttpServletRequest request){ 


    numberForm = nhNumberService.getNumEnquiryList(indexRad); 
    return new ModelAndView("exoectedresult", "form", numberForm); 
}
```

Comment: How about the other way around if i have to set the value of the radio button from backend to the page?